# JsonSerializer deserialize custom JSON

Tags: .net, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I have a `json`-file that has the following format:

```
{"0":{"Height":190,"Left":1640,"Top":170,"Width":600},"1":{"Height":52,"Left":2250,"Top":306,"Width":112},"10":{"Height":38,"Left":2011,"Top":794,"Width":378},"100":{"Height":45,"Left":192,"Top":3318,"Width":131},"101":{"Height":42,"Left":1211,"Top":3367,"Width":1216}}
```

The special case in this `json`-file:

- entries are not sorted with ascending numbers (this is not an issue for me)
- entries are numbered from `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, ... and especially not named correctly like a json list.

I have a class `Geometry` that looks like the following:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to parse the `json`-file by ignoring the "enumeration" `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, and so on and just considers the content of each such node (that translates to class `Geometry`)?
As output I want an object `List<Geometry>`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the JSON represents is effectively a `Dictionary<string, Geometry>` - or if you're happy for the keys to be parsed, a `Dictionary<int, Geometry>`. I'd suggest parsing it *as* that, and then constructing a list from the result. If you don't care about the keys or the order at all, I'd just use:

```cs
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Geometry>>()
    .Values
    .ToList();
```

If you want to use the *value* of the keys for ordering, you could write:

```cs
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Geometry>>()
    .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
    .Values
    .ToList();
```

(I'd expect broadly the same code to work for all JSON libraries.)

Comment: Works like charm, I opted for `System.Text.Json` with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, Geometry>>(jsonContent)`.